# Is there a open source automation tool for Qt app?

Tags: qt, automation, automated-tests

Is there a open source automation tool for Qt app? I'm looking for a automation tool for Qt app, Squish is too expensive

Comment: If Squish is too expensive, you may spent your time and write your own tool. Btw, guys from KDAB have very powerfool tool for introspecting Qt applications. It may be used as a base for your requirements: https://www.kdab.com/development-resources/qt-tools/gammaray/

Comment: @DmitrySazonov thanks for your reply, but it's hard for me to write my own tool. ~. ~

Comment: You might want to use Qt native testing framework (QTestLib) for more or less simple tests. I think, for unit testing you can do anything with it. For GUI automation - only the basic tests, like mouse and/or keyboard simulation.

Comment: Sikulix is an option https://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're OK with writing your tests in Selenium, you can try qtwebdriver

Comment: Where can I find the qtwebdriver?

Comment: My app is not a web, is qtwebdriver available?

Comment: Yes, qtwebdriver can also automate qtwidget, quick1, quick2 etc...apps. The testing can still be done via selenium since the UI of the native app is converted to xml at runtime.  See the github wiki here https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/wiki/Hybridity-And-View-Management, and here https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/wiki/Build-And-Run

Comment: Also search for qtwebdriver on stackoverflow, a lot of questions are already answered